# How do I know where `yo` is running from? How to specify where it runs?

Tags: linux, node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

In the beginning, I had `yo` and `generator-angular` installed on `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (by doing the bad `sudo npm install -g ...`).

Then I read [isaccs' advice on how to make npm and yo work without sudo](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814), and [modified his steps](https://gist.github.com/randwa1k/9061221) to make all the lines work. So I got `yo` and `generator-angular` installed on `~/.node/lib/node_modules` as well.

Finally, suspecting that `yo` might be running from the original directory, I removed `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. I created a brand new directory in "~/" and called `yo angular` in it, but was faced with: `yo: command not found`.

**Is there a command that tells me from which directory `yo` is running from?**

**How can I tell `yo` that it should run from `~/.node/lib/node_modules`?**

---

More info:

My `$PATH`: `/home/ubuntu/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

My `~/.bashrc` contains `export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH`
My `~/.npmrc` contains `prefix = /home/ubuntu/.node`

```
$ ls -l ~/.node/lib/node_modules/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  7 nobody ubuntu 4096 Feb 17 21:57 bower
drwxr-xr-x 19 nobody ubuntu 4096 Feb 22 01:19 generator-angular
drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody ubuntu 4096 Feb 17 22:00 generator-karma
drwxr-xr-x  6 nobody ubuntu 4096 Feb 17 21:57 grunt-cli
drwxr-xr-x 10 nobody ubuntu 4096 Feb 17 23:15 npm
drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody ubuntu 4096 Feb 17 22:00 yo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm):

```
$ curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
```

2.Use nvm to install node and npm. Reopen your terminal and run the following commands in turn:

```
$ nvm install 0.10.26

$ npm install -g yo

$ npm install -g generator-angular
```

`yo` and `generator-angular` will be installed in `~/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules`. You can run them directly in the terminal now:

```
$ yo -v
```

3.Run `which yo` to find the directory `yo` is running from.

Comment: Is it `npm install -g generator-angular` instead of `npm install -g yo-angular`?. And it didn't go into my ~/.nvm, it went into `/home/ubuntu/local/bin/`. Perhaps because I did `export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/ubuntu/local/lib/node_modules` to ~/.bashrc

Comment: Yes, It should be `npm install-g genrator-angular`. Fixed it. You should undo what you have done previously, the install nvm.